# After I use try catch how do i jump back into the while loop?

Tags: java, try-catch

not the whole program but what this program does is that it takes a bunch of numbers and separates the even and odds.

```
     public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);//for user input
        int[] evenNum = new int [100];//Even Array up too 100
        int[] oddNum = new int[100];//Odd Array up too 100
        int evenIndex=0;//even numbers
        int input=0;//user input
        int i=0;//incrementer for arrays
        int k=0; 
        int j=0;

        String name;
        System.out.println("Type In Your Name");//Type in name 
        name = stdin.nextLine();

        try{
   while ((i < oddNum.length && i < evenNum.length) && input != -1)
  //Makes sure no more than 100 numbers can be placed.
        {

            System.out.println(name+" Enter a positive number, Enter -1 For results");
            input= stdin.nextInt();
            oddNum[i]=input;
            i++;//Increments array

            }
            }
        catch(Exception d)
        {
            System.out.println("Only Numbers Please");//Makes sure only numbers can be displayed

        }
```

I have tried using return but this is a type void so I cant.Is their a pass reference i can use? .

Comment: Why don't you just `try` it in the loop and not the whole loop?

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly if you are asking people to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `try catch` inside the `while` loop

```
while ((i < oddNum.length && i < evenNum.length) && input != -1)
//Makes sure no more than 100 numbers can be placed.
{
    try {
        System.out.println(name+" Enter a positive number, Enter -1 For results");
        input= stdin.nextInt();
        oddNum[i]=input;
        i++;//Increments array
    }
    catch(Exception d)
    {
        System.out.println("Only Numbers Please");//Makes sure only numbers can be displayed
    }
}
```

Comment: i did that but the catch part continues to appear in an infinite loop

Comment: @Ronaldo I would assume it because `stdin` still has something to read from the console. Insert `scanner.next();` to the `catch` clause.

Comment: Also, you are probably failing before the increment of i, so you never increase i!

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception where you actually want to handle it.

Consider your structure:

```
try {
  while {
    //...
  }
} catch {
  //...
}
```

When you're in the `catch` block, the `while` block is finished.  The flow has exited that block, and thus there's no return path to it.  Basically, the loop is over.

On the other hand, consider this:

```
while {
  try {
    //...
  } catch {
    //...
  }
}
```

In this case, when you exit the `catch` block, you're still in the `while` block.  So the loop can continue.

Comment: i put the try catch in the while loop but i seem to get a continuous loop "dh Enter a positive number, Enter -1 For results
Only Numbers Please" Keeps appearing

Comment: @Ronaldo: An infinite loop means your loop condition never ends.  You'd have to step through in a debugger to determine why that condition isn't changing (and where you think it should be).